# Webpack: how to output multiple types of the same source (i.e. dev, prod, etc...)

Tags: javascript, webpack

Is there a way to produce multiple versions of the same source files? For example, if I wanted to produce a minified and production ready build but also produce the dev version that is no obfuscated and has sourcemap annotations. Or do I have have to run webpack multiple times for the specified environments to produce the different outputs?

Comment: Do you have an issue with running it multiple times? It seems the most obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by exporting an array of configuration objects:

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations

```
// Typical single configuration object
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: '...',
  output: ...
}

// Multiple configurations array
module.exports = [
  {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: '...',
    output: ...
  },
  {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: '...',
    output: ...
  }
]
```